# How does $F=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n c_{ij}\dot q_i\dot q_j\implies\frac{\partial{\ F}}{\partial\dot{q_r}}=\sum_{j=1}^nc_{q_rj}\dot q_j$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, classical-mechanics

How does $F=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n c_{ij}\dot q_i\dot q_j\implies\frac{\partial{\ F}}{\partial\dot{q_r}}=\sum_{j=1}^nc_{q_rj}\dot q_j$?

I'm not getting how $c_{ij} $ gets transformed to $c_{q_rj}$ and how does the factor $\frac{1}{2}$ vanish...

The original source is https://www.kvi.nl/~scholten/AAM/Friction-Lagrange.pdf

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is just an abuse of notation to highlight the variable $q_r$ and it's equivalent to

$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial \dot q_r}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}c_{rj}\dot q_j=-Q^N_r
$$

Answer (score 0):

$c_{q_r j}$ makes no sense to me, the correct answer would be $c_{rj}$ since $\frac{\partial \dot q_i}{\partial \dot q_r}=\delta_{ir}$.

For the $1/2$ factor, try to apply the product rule of derivatives.

Comment: :On applying chain rule i'm getting $\frac{\partial{\ F}}{\partial\dot{q_r}}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n [c_{ij}\delta_{ir}\dot q_j+c_{ij}\delta_{jr}\dot q_i]$.But,if $i=j=r$,then we're getting our result...

Comment: :Thanks a lot....

Comment: @PK You cannot assume $i=j=r$, this can be seen if you write down the sum $\Sigma$ with the numerical indices. You have to realize $\Sigma_i c_{ij} \delta_{ir}= c_{jr}$. Then, you get a term summed over $i$ and another over $j$. Convince yourself that they are the same if you substitute the induces by the numerical values.

Comment: You will encounter this type of tricks everywhere in physics.